# C Array read optimization

Tags: c

As input I have one line:

```
2 6 7 5 1 2 3 4 5    
A a b B c d e f g
```

Where **A** - integer, how many numbers in `Array1`, then `a b` - numbers in `Array1`, then **B** - integer, how many numbers in `Array2`, `c d e f g` - numbers in `Array2`

I write this code:

```
scanf("%d", &Alen); // read Array1 len
int posA[Alen];
for (i = 0; i < Alen; i++){
        scanf("%d", &posA[i]);//read Array1 numbers
    }

scanf("%d", &Blen);//read Array2 len
int posB[Blen];
for (i = 0; i < Blen; i++){//read Array2 numbers
        scanf("%d", &posB[i]);
    }
```

But it is so slow (slowest, than my program, doining something with this arrays), so may be there is another way to scan this arrays, and do this quick?

Comment: You mean slow, because you'll have to manually input the numbers?

Comment: How do you define **quick**? You know this constant factor shouldn't be a big issue under most circumstances. If you insist, try `fread()` to read it into a large chunk of file then parse it yourself or use `sscanf()`. (It will be faster, as I found out on several Online Judges.) Or, use memory mapping to parse the file.

Comment: @bash.d Nope. I use unit-test input, so the problem is this algo

Comment: @phoeagon Faster, than my algo.

Comment: @Ansh predefined? NO! Random arrays

Comment: Maybe you should do as phoeagon suggested. It sounds good.

Comment: How can I you sscanf() to int[] Array?

Comment: How large is the actual data that you are measuring over?

Comment: @MatsPetersson <10^4. About ~1000

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that would take sufficiently long to worry about - how long does the input take?

Comment: @MatsPetersson > 5 sec on my i7. Slow...

Comment: Huh? 5 seconds to read 1000 numbers, or 1000 lines of numbers?

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin I do have experience in optimizing IO when writing a `quicksort` in C++ hoping to beat the implementation by my classmates using Pascal. I used `scanf` and I failed. Then I won by switching to this nasty solution.

Comment: If you are interested, read (http://www.byvoid.com/blog/fast-readfile/). You may need a online translator to read Chinese. But still, I can tell you that the author suggests custom integer parser + memory mapped file.

Comment: There's something more to this than what you state. I just implemented your code on my Linux machine, and it takes 0.013s to read 22295 numbers [that's  3186 copies of your example line above].

Comment: @MatsPetersson ok, I look at my code again! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try atoi / strtok instead of scanf. That might be faster.

Comment: It is very likely something else not right. Or the measurement isn't of the input phase - or the data being input isn't what I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this constant factor makes a big deal under most circumstances. But still if you insist on improving it... you may try this:

```
#define BIGBIG_SIZE (10000000)
char* buffer=(char*)malloc(BIGBIG_SIZE); // make it big enough for your file.
                              // makes your life easier by making sure 
                              //the whole file could be read in once
fread( buffer , 1 , BIGBIG_SIZE , stdin );
sscanf( buffer , "%d", &a ); // from now on use sscanf to get from buffer instead of scanf()
```

This works for me sometimes. (I happened to find that `scanf("%d")` is *indeed* something like 2x slower than `read(x)` in pascal) If necessary, write your own routine to get *tokens* (integers).

If it's still too slow, try using memory mapped file instead of `fread` into a buffer.

```
fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Error opening file for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
map = mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
      close(fd);
      perror("Error mmapping the file");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// then you use sscanf() here
```

Or any other memory mapping solution on your platform.

---

Still, I don't think you need these dirty tricks.